# Protractor - can't click on angular material tag

Tags: angular, protractor

I create teste with Protractor and need click on **md-icon** tag. I used several selctors:

```css
*[ng-reflect-title="Add"]
/* Or */
#add
/* Or */
md-icon#add
```

In code I wrote somthing like this:

```js
protractor.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(by.css('#add')), 5000).then((el: webdriver.IWebElement) => {
  resolve(el.click());
});
```

At local machine all works fine butn at *travis-ci* have error that element not found. [Link](https://travis-ci.org/bulktrade/SMSC/builds/164892621#L2879)

Any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error from the link you provided says: `Wait timed out after 5087ms`.  The element was not located within the 5 second timeout you provided, so you need to extend that since it seems your tests are running slower on CI than locally.  So maybe try 10 seconds (or even longer):

`protractor.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(by.css('#add')), 10000).then(...)`

In the situations like this, your use of implicit waits is correct and a good practice.  Personally I never have a problem with extending those implicit waits, because it's not a guaranteed wait timer.  The tests fire ASAP once that element is found, so it's more of a stability feature.

Comment: where is the full api for all these `protractor.` methods ? For example, I'm not finding `.until` on the api page here http://www.protractortest.org/#/api

Comment: @bob.mazzo The syntax was weird to me too, it almost looks like he's using [Selenium Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) instead of Protractor's.  But it very closely resembled [Expected Conditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions), plus his error was about a timeout so that was easy to pinpoint.  Just to be clear, I always use Expected Conditions with a `browser.wait()`.  Not the syntax like above.

Comment: Both of those links you provided clear it up for me (i.e. Selenium contains the `wait.until`). Thanks so much.